# Custom Excel Ribbon background colors (like design with tables)

Tags: excel, ribbon

I have used CustomUIEditor to make many excel ribbons. I haven't been able to figure out how to change the background color of custom tabs I make. I'd like to change the background color of my tabs so they are noticeable as custom. I'm thinking of the same method excel uses when you click on a table and the color behind the design tab presents.

Like this:

[image]

Comment: I believe that the ribbon colors (and whatnot) is controlled by the Theme, which is set for the Application. I've not seen where someone has managed to override the Theme for a particular tab of the Ribbon.

Comment: I don't think you can color your custom tabs. The colored tabs that you refer to are not normal tabs, they are called contextual tabs and are only visible when you are editing a table etc. You can read more about them on [Ron de Bruins site](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win006.htm).

Answer (score 4):

While VBA can create and modify ribbons (and even add images) it can't change the overall color of the ribbon as seen when the ribbon is not selected.

To change the ribbon color, you need a COM add-in.  COM add-ins are different than regular add-ins.  Instead of using VBA (which at first glance looks like Visual Basic and is similar to an outdated version of VB), COM add-ins utilize modern Visual Basic or Visual C++.

How to write a COM add-in for Excel is beyond the scope of the question but here are some resources to get you started from Microsoft and Chuck Pearson:

[About Excel COM Add-ins](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/291392)

[Creating a COM Add-in](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/creatingcomaddin.aspx)

[Customizing Ribbon Colors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd940487(v=vs.85).aspx)